# RegEx grouping with default value if not found using PHP

Tags: php, regex

Here is an example string:

```
$text = 'foo (20/50) bar () baz (11/30)';
```

The output I need is this:

```
$items = array(
   array(
      "title" => "foo",
      "number" => 20
   ),
   array(
      "title" => "bar",
      "number" => 0
   )
   array(
      "title" => "baz",
      "number" => 11
   )
);
```

#### Attempt

Up until now, I've been using

```
$matches_title = array();
$matches_number = array();
preg_match_all('!([^\s]+)!',$text,$matches_title);
preg_match_all('!(?<=\()(\d+)(?=\/)!',$text,$matches_number);
```

And then looping through the matches to catch the values. Obviously, this doesn't work when one of the parenthesis is empty since both arrays will have different lengths.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You may preprocess the string like `str_replace('()', '(0)', $text)` and run the regex on this string. There is no way to use a "default group value", regex does not work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this php code:

```
$text = 'foo (20/50) bar () baz (11/30)';
preg_match_all('~([\w-]+)\h*\((\d*)(?=[/)])~', $text, $m);

$items = array();
foreach($m[1] as $i => $v) {
   $n = $m[2][$i];
   $items[] = array( "title" => $v, "number" => (empty($n) ? 0: $n) );
}
print_r($items);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => foo
            [number] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => bar
            [number] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => baz
            [number] => 11
        )

)
```

Comment: This will also match `foo (30)`. We should find out if this is a possibility and whether it should be included in the result.

Comment: @Barmar I don't believe it is a possibility, but even if it were it would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to match the format of your string using `\G` to assert the position at the end of the previous match and use a named capturing group:

```
\G(?<title>\S+)\h+\((?:(?<number>\d+)/\d+)?\)(?:\s|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7cFn8o/1/) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/viRCn)

For example:

```
$str = "foo (20/50) bar () baz (11/30)";
$pattern = '~\G(?<title>\S+)\h+\((?:(?<number>\d+)/\d+)?\)(?:\s|$)~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$matches = array_reduce($matches, function($carry, $item) {
    $carry[] = [
        "title" => $item["title"],
        "number" => array_key_exists("number", $item) ? $item["number"] : 0

    ];
    return $carry;
});


print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => foo
            [number] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => bar
            [number] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => baz
            [number] => 11
        )

)
```